# Exclude certain rows from filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet of tools.

The first column has a hierarchical structure that indicates where the tool is located. I have some header rows that have things such as cabinets, drawers, etc. I would like to be able to use filter to search by tool name, model, type, etc. and have it retain the location headers so that the tool locations can be seen.

The goal is for this to be relatively easy to modify, whether it be adding new locations (should be as easy as adding a new row with the location name and editing a style or similar for that row) or moving tools to different locations, so hardcoding the location names or ranges is not an option.

What the table looks like

[image: What the table looks like]

What it should look like after filtering for Type=2

[image: What it should look like after filtering for Type=2]

Comment: Please check whether the pivot table is helpful.

Comment: @Emily It doesn't look helpful, since pivot tables are built to sum cells together, and I can't get it to do anything other than that (besides averaging, product, count, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider your grouping obvious, but Excel has no idea that your indentation means a grouping. There is no way in the standard functionality to make it consider indentation as grouping.
However, it *has* a grouping builtin, which is made for exactly that. Try around with it, snd you will be able to make it do what you wanted (it's to complex to explain it all here, but not difficult - just try a bit).

Comment: I have everything grouped now, but it still filters out the group headers as if the group is not there

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the precise data and layout, you could do the following. It would work due to the fact that your higher level entries ("headers" of a kind) all have no entry in the Type column.

Filters of the kind used in the column headers of a Table all offer the value of "Blanks" if blanks indeed exist in their rows. Not so the `FILTER()` function and formulas that do similar things, but you are using the Table's filtering capability so you can do this.

Simply check the checkbox for the Type value/s that you wish to filter for AND the checkbox for Blanks (which will be the last item in the list of filtering choices.

Then the higher level headings will still show. Since the items "in" them are below them, the hierarchical setup will maintain itself as you show as desirable.

You could find that users forget the (Blanks) checkbox. They'll remember when they don't see the headers. But if you can allow the header rows' values to be something other than a literal blank, or quite a few variations that Excel sees as blanks, pick a low numbered character that displays no visible character in the cell, but alphabetizes at the start of a list, then it will be at the top, just below the "Select All" checkbox that heads it.

I seem to have difficulty doing that easily. The `Alt-2` character doesn't come up blank and `Alt-002` or `Alt-+002` don't put anything in a cell for me. Doing something wrong, I assume, but... However, putting the formula `=UNICHAR(2)` in a cell, then copying and pasting as a value does, and it is the blank character one expects but is not treated as a blank by Excel in the Filter so it fits the bill. Strange steps to have to go through, but it does do the trick and if someone sets up new things, not users doing it, it's not the weirdest Excel thing you'll ever do. ("2" is not only just about the lowest numbered character so will be at the top of almost anything, but the first 32 characters in the ASCII set are traditionally seldom used for anything directly. Character 10, of course, being a common exception in Excel, but 2<10 so...)

Other alternatives exist that do not require wholesale revamping of the data structure, but the simplest that comes to me would still require a helper column in the table that formulaically does the above. So enter a value in one column, and a formula in the other column's rows (copied down, not a dynamic array formula as Tables do not allow those) generates that character, or your `UNICHAR(2)` if that column's row is empty, and you Filter THAT column, the formula bearing column, not the column entries are made in. Awkward, if you are doing this for users. Not a thing at all if doing the work with it yourself. (If the latter, one need not have the helper column as one could easily enter things for the session, then enter the `=UNICHAR(2)` function somewhere and paste its value in the new work's hierarchical rows.)

Comment: The issue I see is that this only works if filtering by Type, but if I want to filter by something else, the filtering of Type can only make it more strict, not less